# React Native (or alternative) that supports native "share via" feature

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I need to create a wrapper app. Basically it is just a webview pointed to our online hosted react app. It must build to both iOS and Android. Therefore I have considered using plain react native.

Most important feature is that the app must be registered on the device as an app that can handle links when using the native "share" feature.

Example; if I do a google search in chrome/safari/whatever I am able to press-hold any of the links (search results) I can then click "share" this will normally open a menu with lets say share to; "drive", "gmail", "messenger", "sms".... etc. I want our wrapper app to show up in the menu and be able to handle the link.

I have tried to search for libraries/frameworks that makes this possible. But all search result I am getting seems to be explanation on how to do the **opposite** thing, *opening the native share menu from within the app.*

I have been looking at expo, but can't figure out if they support this feature, otherwise I would consider create-react-native-app which is react-native based, but I am also not able to find direct documentation on how to implement such feature.

Further more, I know that there is a unity plugin that will do this, and that I could combine it with a uniWebView which would handle the wrapper app part.

**How can I achieve a native share to feature on a simple wrapper app that builds to both iOS and Android?**

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do that in react native on Android because its not part of the native code.  Its part of the manifest.  You need to follow the instructions at https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive and set up an intent filter in your manifest telling the OS your app handles the correct mime type, and what activity to send it to.  That activity would then have to handle the incoming data, either directly or by sending it to react native (which is going to be at least a mild pain, RN is ok when you want it to display a isolated view or want it to call a native module, calling RN code isn't very easy).  This doesn't mean your app can't use react native, but that you'll need to modify the default manifest it creates.

If that's a major usecase of your app and your app is 90% just displaying your webpage, you may have an easier time of things not using react native and just displaying a web view.  (I'll leave my bias of RN just being a horrible solution for everything at the door here).

Comment: Thanks! That probably explains why my searches haven't been successful. Do you know if the same applies for iOS ?